# algebraic form to polar form in complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I represent $ (1+i)^n + (1-i)^n $ in the polar form?

So far I've reached this: $ (1+i)^n + (1-i)^n = 2^\frac{n+2}{2}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$

Comment: @DonThousand Those surds shouldn't be reciprocated. Further, they pick up a power of $n$ later.

Comment: @J.G. Sorry, what does "surd" mean?

Comment: $1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$, and $1-i=\sqrt2e^{-i\pi/4}$. So, in polar form, it's $$2^{n/2}\left(e^{in\pi/4}+e^{-in\pi/4}\right)$$

Comment: @DonThousand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surd_(mathematics)

Comment: @J.G. Wow, learn something new everyday. Is it a well known term?

Comment: @DonThousand I encountered it in a GCSE Maths Textbook, so yes.

Comment: I don't think that SE should help with homework. At least you should tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

The sum is real, so in polar form it's $2^{n/2+1}|\cos\tfrac{n\pi}{4}|e^{i\pi k}$, where $k=0$ if the cosine is positive or $k=1$ if it's negative. If the cosine is $0$, the sum is $0$, so its phase is arbitrary. You can work out for yourself which values of $n$, modulo $8$, end up in each of these three options.